# JScript for PDF to enter the current date regardless if text-field is full or empty

Tags: javascript, date, pdf

I'm having a small problem with my PDF document. I've got a text-field called "date", and in it I execute this Jscript code:

```
if(event.value == "")
{
event.value = util.printd("dd.mm.yyyy", new Date())
}

if(event.value != "")
{
event.value = util.printd("dd.mm.yyyy", new Date())
}
```

Now, it works just fine on it's own, but it doesn't do the job exactly like I want it to.

Say, if I opened the document on 01.07.2014, then the date would be 01.07.2014, then I saved the document, and that was it.

Now I open the document on 20.07.2014, the date still is 01.07.2014. I have to at least remove 1 character for the Jscript to do its job.  I want the "date" text field to be changed when I open the document.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, it is JavaScript!

The problem is that for your scenario, using the field events is not the best way (as you have seen).

When you want the field display the date when you have opened the document, you would use the PageOpen event (in Acrobat XI, it is well hidden: open the Thumbnails panel, select the concerned page, open the page properties via context menu, and switch to the Actions tab).

The simplest way is to add this code to the Open Page script:

```
this.getField("myOpeningDateField").value = util.printd("dd.mm.yyyy", new Date() ) ;
```

This works well with a single page document, but if you have multiple pages, it will run whenever you get to that page. To run it only once you have to protect it, by doing this:

1) you create a document-level script which contains only this line:

```
var loaded = 0 ;
```

2) you modify the Open Page code as follows:

```
if (loaded == 0) {
this.getField("myOpeningDateField").value = util.printd("dd.mm.yyyy", new Date() ) ;
loaded++ ;
}
```

And that should do it.